# MySQL Filter Where if Column= NULL or Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Python with MYSql string queries and trying to do something like

```
"SELECT id from Example
WHERE item_column = (%s)"
```

Where in my case the passed in value can be a number or NULL. I understand that in SQL NULL represents nothing so this equality will not work. Normally, I would have to do something like column IS NULL. However, how do I set up my statement to account for values that can be NULL or not NULL?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`NULL`-safe equal operator `<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```
"SELECT id from Example WHERE item_column <=> (%s)"
```

Comment: I had no idea this existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want give a default value for your variable incase its null you can use coalese(say 'xx' in case of string and -99.99 in case of integer)

```
"SELECT id from Example
WHERE item_column = COALESCE((%s),-99.99)"
```

But if you want to modify your statement based on the whether variable is null or not then you have to do a if else in the code

```
if variable is None:
     return "SELECT id from Example WHERE item_column  is null"
else:
     return "SELECT id from Example WHERE item_column = variable"
```

Comment: What is the 'XX' in this case? Could this be any truthy value?

Comment: yes. you can mention a string literal ('xx') or integer literal(-99.99)